# How to capture mouse cursor in Java?

Tags: java, awt, mouse, awtrobot

Ok, Most of you will think it's a duplicate because it's already written everywhere that it's not really doable and the only option is to do a screenshot using awt robot.

But... The issue is that the mouse cursor does not even appear in the picture produced by AWT robot... I tries gnome-screeshots and there I can see the mouse cursor. But from the java screenshot, nothing. The entire picture, but not mouse cursor. It's like it's hidding it before taking the picture. I search for a parameter like setIncludeMouseCursor or anything like that with no luck.

I can capture the mouse location, that's fine. But if I capture just this area, again no cursor.

Any idea how to enforce robot.createScreenCapture to capture also the mouse cursor?

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `MouseInfo` class and use its method static `getPointerInfo()` to get a `Pointer` object to represent the position of your cursor on the screen.

Once you have the position, you can use `Robot` to take a screenshot as a `BufferedImage` and draw the cursor on it. Simple !

**SSCCE**

```
package stack;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class GetMousePointer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String USER_HOME = System.getProperty("user.home");

        GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
        int height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();

        BufferedImage blackSquare = new BufferedImage(50, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        for(int i = 0; i < blackSquare.getHeight(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < blackSquare.getWidth(); j++){
                blackSquare.setRGB(j, i, 128);
            }
        }


        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            BufferedImage screenshot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0,0,width,height));
            PointerInfo pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            int x = (int) pointer.getLocation().getX();
            int y = (int) pointer.getLocation().getY();

            screenshot.getGraphics().drawImage(blackSquare, x, y, null);
            ImageIO.write(screenshot, "PNG", new File(USER_HOME, "screenshot.PNG"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**
[image]

The top-left corner of the blue square is the position of my cursor.

Comment: Well shucks!  I was going to say that.  But since you not only said it, but provided code..  +1  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson You can't troll meee !! xD

Comment: The issue is, what I want is the cursor picture. I want to know if it's an arrow, a double arrow, etc. I need to take an action based on the form of the cursor :(

Comment: @jmspaggi I do not believe that you can get that information with pure Java. You will need a lower level API to interface with your Java program via JNI / JNA.

Comment: Great code! Still wonder why java.awt.Robot don't provide an option to include cursor...

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `Robot` and override `createScreenCapture` to (given the cursor position) draw in the capture a cursor.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public BufferedImage createScreenCapture(){
    BufferedImage img = Super.createScreenCapture();
    return drawCursor(x,y,img); 
}
```

Obvioulsy `drawCursor` returns a `BufferedImage`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the same comment as above. I need to cursor picture. Not only a picture where the cursor is :(